# How to write a proper dataset_fn in tff.simulation.FilePerUserClientData?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I'm currently implementing federated learning using `tff`.

Because the dataset is very large, we split it into many npy files, and I'm currently putting the dataset together using [`tff.simulation.FilePerUserClientData`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/simulation/FilePerUserClientData).

This is what I'm trying to do

```
client_ids_to_files = dict()
for i in range(len(train_filepaths)):
  client_ids_to_files[str(i)] = train_filepaths[i]

def dataset_fn(filepath):
  print(filepath)
  dataSample = np.load(filepath)
  label = filepath[:-4].strip().split('_')[-1]
  return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dataSample, label))
train_filePerClient = tff.simulation.FilePerUserClientData(client_ids_to_files,dataset_fn)
```

However, it doesn't seem to work well, the `filepath` in the callback function has is a tensor with dtype of string. The value of `filepath` is: `Tensor("hash_table_Lookup/LookupTableFindV2:0", shape=(), dtype=string)`

Instead of containing a path in `client_ids_to_files`, the tensor seems to contains error messages? Am I doing something wrong? How can I write a proper dataset_fn for `tff.simulation.FilePerUserClientData` using npy files?

*EDIT*:
Here is the error log. The error itself is not really related to the question I'm asking, but you can find the called functions:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-e61ddbe06cdb> in <module>
     22     return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filepath)
     23 
---> 24 train_filePerClient = tff.simulation.FilePerUserClientData(client_ids_to_files,dataset_fn)
     25 

~/fasttext-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/simulation/file_per_user_client_data.py in __init__(self, client_ids_to_files, dataset_fn)
     52       return dataset_fn(client_ids_to_files[client_id])
     53 
---> 54     @computations.tf_computation(tf.string)
     55     def dataset_computation(client_id):
     56       client_ids_to_path = tf.lookup.StaticHashTable(

~/fasttext-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/core/impl/wrappers/computation_wrapper.py in __call__(self, tff_internal_types, *args)
    405                                             parameter_type)
    406       args, kwargs = unpack_arguments_fn(next(wrapped_fn_generator))
--> 407       result = fn_to_wrap(*args, **kwargs)
    408       if result is None:
    409         raise ComputationReturnedNoneError(fn_to_wrap)

~/fasttext-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/simulation/file_per_user_client_data.py in dataset_computation(client_id)
     59               list(client_ids_to_files.values())), '')
     60       client_path = client_ids_to_path.lookup(client_id)
---> 61       return dataset_fn(client_path)
     62 
     63     self._create_tf_dataset_fn = create_dataset_for_filename_fn

<ipython-input-46-e61ddbe06cdb> in dataset_fn(filepath)
     17         filepath = tf.print(filepath)
     18     print(filepath)
---> 19     dataSample = np.load(filepath)
     20     print(dataSample)
     21     label = filepath[:-4].strip().split('_')[-1]

~/fasttext-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in load(file, mmap_mode, allow_pickle, fix_imports, encoding)
    426         own_fid = False
    427     else:
--> 428         fid = open(os_fspath(file), "rb")
    429         own_fid = True
    430 

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Operation
```

Comment: Could the question be extended to include the error message, stack trace, and add more details about what the "callback function" is? This will help provide better answers.

Comment: @ZacharyGarrett Sorry I was confused about the error before, I edited my post to clarify my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `dataset_fn` must be serializable as a [`tf.Graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph). This is required because TFF uses TensorFlow graphs to execute logic on remote machines.

In this case, `np.load` is not serializable to a graph operation. It looks like numpy is used to load from disk in to memory, and then `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` is used to create a dataset from an in-memory object? I may be possible to save the file in a different format and use a native `tf.data.Dataset` operation to load from disk, rather than using Python. Some options could be [`tf.data.TFRecordDataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TFRecordDataset), [`tf.data.TextLineDataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TextLineDataset), or [`tf.data.experimental.SqlDataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/SqlDataset).